# Target a link if that link links to the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this may be a stupid question as I can't seem to find an answer :P

Is there a way with javascript/jQuery to Target all links on a page ONLY if they link to the current page?

Say i've got a static sidebar on ALL pages, for intents and purposes:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
    <li><a href="/one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="/three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice the code for ALL of them is the same. Let's say I'm on "www.domain.com/two" - Is there a way to target

```
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
```

because it's linking to the current page?

****ANSWERED**************

The guy deleted his answer - but I used it to create this -

```
var linksToCurrentPage = $('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]');
if (linksToCurrentPage) {
    $('a').addClass('currently-active');
};
```

which worked :)

Comment: I changed the question. The links are absolute, not relative :/

Comment: var linksToCurrentPage = $('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]');
    if (linksToCurrentPage) {
  $('a').addClass('currently-active');
};

this worked

Comment: Are you trying to change the link href to the current page href to `#?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sidebar">
    <li><a href="/one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="/three">Three</a></li>
</ul>


<script>
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
//$("a:contains('One')").css("color", "red"); // This will make One red (notice capital O)
$("a:contains(pathname)").css("color", "red");

</script>
```

​