# How can I keep CSS style select for menu item clicked

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

This is my HTML Code for menu

```
<div style="visibility:visible; color: #FFF; top:125px; width:100%; height:40px; position:absolute; display:block;background:#2B63B3;">
<ul id="trans-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Academic</a>
     <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Miscellanous</a>
     <ul>
       <li> <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a> </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This the CSS code for menu

```
#trans-nav { list-style-type: none; height: 40px; padding: 0px 15px; margin: 0px; }
#trans-nav li { float: left; width:110px; position: relative; padding: 0px; line-height: 40px; background: #2B63B3; text-align:center; }
#trans-nav li a { display: block; padding: 0 15px; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
#trans-nav li a:hover { color: #97B7E6; }
#trans-nav li ul { opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 8em; background: #2B63B3; list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;  z-index:1;}
#trans-nav li:hover ul { opacity: 1; }
#trans-nav li ul li { float: none; position: static; height: 0; line-height: 0; background: none; }
#trans-nav li:hover ul li { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; }
#trans-nav li ul li a { background: #2B63B3; }
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover { background: #2B63B3; }
```

When I hover on any menu item color gets changed and when I click on item it navigates to the page but the the color of the text revert back to white. I want to keep the changed color till any other menu item is not clicked.

Any advice, suggestion or guidance is appreciable.

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: Are you saying you want the menu item representing the current page to stay white? So if you click Sub Menu 1, the Sub Menu 1 item is white when you hover again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Target a link if that link links to the current page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951444/target-a-link-if-that-link-links-to-the-current-page)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall NO I want to say when I hover the Links it color change from white to light blue. Now suppose I click on Sub Menu 1 of Miscellanous main menu then Miscellanous color should be light blue its should not turn back to ita original color that is white.

Comment: @Paulie_D link you mentioned is not what I am asking my question is totally different. Kindly check it again

Answer (score 1):

You can add a '.current' class to the anchor tag, via javascript.  And give it those styles.

(Or if your nav is seperate on all pages just add it to the current pages nav, no need for js.)

Comment: I'm agree with @Andrew Ice, [here you have a fast example](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/S6p5f/) about how it could be.

Comment: @Andrew Ice thank you for guidance but I want to aviod javascript and my nav in a menu.php file which I will include in other .php files

Comment: JS is pretty much unavoidable in this instance. If this is WP, i believe there is a plug-in for 'current page'.

Comment: Yeah, well, the only exception is this.
Have a nav bar on every single page of your website and add that current class, into the html itself.

That's the only way to avoid javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your suggestion i implemented the code suggested by Andrew Ice and NewPatrik, but why the main menu doesn't hold the color when I click any sub menu, in fact color is preserved by the sub menu, but sub menu is not visible to the users, hence the main menu should preserve the color even if user click on sub menu. So as per you how can I avoid JS as you know then I have to write code for about 347 pages. Any idea

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying here.  We may need more examples.

Comment: @AndrewIce Its very simple See for example- If clicked on Home color changed and remain changed till I clicked on About Us, this perfect. <br> But if I click on Sub Menu 1 of Academic then color of Sub Menu 1 changed but the color of Academic is not changing. <br> What I am asking how is it possible to keep the color changed for Academic.

Comment: Just add the class to the parent element (li) as well.